# Why does a unix timestamp need to be prefixed by '@' for strtotime() to understand it?

Tags: php, strtotime

I noticed that `strtotime()` handles unix timestamps in an odd way, and I was curious if anyone knows why that is:

```
var_export(strtotime('1330725042'));  // false
var_export(strtotime('@1330725042')); // 1330725042
```

Why does `strtotime()` return `false` when given a unix timestamp (unless said timestamp is prefixed by `@`)?

This is from the internals of a library method that I built that is intended to "resolve" an unknown-format variable into a timestamp. Using a bare `strtotime()` isn't helpful in this case because it returns the wrong result when the incoming value actually is a timestamp.

I've reworked the library method to do an explicit check for a timestamp-like value and return it unmodified, so there's... shall we say, no practical application for this question anymore; I'm just curious.

Comment: Because the documentation says so :) http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php I don't think a integer is a valid Date/Time format

Comment: +1 for that link Mathieu. I figured there were docs on it *somewhere*.

Comment: Thanks. I actually had no idea that a unix timestamp could be a valid PHP DateTime format.

Comment: @Mathieu - post that as an answer because it actually answers the second part of the question

Comment: why would you convert a time into a...time?

Comment: @dqhendricks I was wondering when someone would ask that (:  I updated my question with some more info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The string that `strtotime()` receives has to be in a specific format. http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php

If `strtotime()` does not recognize the input format, it returns `FALSE`. As unix time is just a sequence of numbers, it cannot properly parse them unless you explicitly specify what format you are using. Putting an `@` at the start gives the function the instruction that this sequence is in unix time format.

For more information, here is the documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: Thanks for the links.  I found this:  'Unix Timestamp "@" "-"? [0-9]+ "@1215282385"' at http://php.net/datetime.formats.compound

Answer (score 2):

Probably because `strtotime` converts *to* a UNIX timestamp, so it's not expecting one as a parameter.

Read [more](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 1):

Because strtotime means **string to time** and your "1330725042" is not a time string but a unix timestamp wrapped in quotes.

strtotime() is meant to be used for values like "2-March-2012".

If you already have 1330725042 as a unix timestamp value, then why do you need to use strtotime()?

Comment: WRT why call `strtotime()` on a timestamp, the motivation behind this question is situations where the code doesn't know that the value is already a timestamp.  I've updated my question with more info.

Comment: You might be using someone's library which calls strtotime on what you supply, and you have a timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

strtotime() outputs timestamp, and its parameter should by text representation of date, so you are using it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that a leading `@` signifies a unix timestamp date format, whereas an integer on its own is an invalid date format. see: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php

Why `strtotime('@1 a')` gives a non-erroneous result of -3599 however, I have no idea. lol

Answer (score 0):

strtotime does not recognize unix timestamps but plain english dates or relative time (like "+1 day" or "1 month")

the @ before the value will surely trigger the "ignore error" mode of php within the call, (interesting side effect) thus letting the unparsable value be returned to the var dump.

Comment: `"@1215282385"` is actually a valid format. Take a look at the link in the comments.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to -1 this, as the presence of `@` has nothing to do with suppressing an error in this case; it's just part of [PHP's documented format for unix timestamps](http://php.net/datetime.formats.compound).

Answer (score 0):

Everyone else is correct in the usage of the function and that it accepts a string and not a timestamp string. However, if you are getting results using an @ sign then likely it is an operator to signify the following text is a timestamp OR that the function is bypassing errors as per PHP's standard usage of @.

Either way, why would you want to strtotime a timestamp?

Comment: WRT why call `strtotime()` on a timestamp, the motivation behind this question is situations where the code doesn't know that the value is already a timestamp.  I've updated my question with more info.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to -1 this, as the presence of `@` has nothing to do with suppressing an error in this case; it's just part of [PHP's documented format for unix timestamps](http://php.net/datetime.formats.compound).

Answer (score -1):

`strtotime()` is meant to convert an English date format into a unix timestamp, so providing a unix timestamp instead of a date format would not be a valid use of this function. Accepted date and time formats can be seen on the php manual at http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php