# strtotime doesn't return false with a valid timestamp

Tags: php, strtotime

Any idea why this

```
strtotime('1356532858')  //Wed, 26 Dec 2012 14:40:58 GMT
```

returns `28043243813` while

```
strtotime('1356055871')  //Fri, 21 Dec 2012 02:11:11 GMT
```

returns `false`?

I'm searching for a solution where I can translate any common date string into a valid timestamp. Unfortunately there are some (valid) timestamps included as well

Comment: Could be because thats when the [world ended](http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/maya-world-end.html) (in case you missed it).

Comment: haha, good one :) But since I'm still here I guess this something different

Comment: If you have a UNIX timestamp, you don't need to use `strtotime` on it ion the first place!

Comment: @deceze how do you check if a string is an UNIX timestamp?

Comment: Hopefully you'd *know* what time format you're dealing with without needing to check that. However, you could check with `ctype_digit()` or `is_int()`. Maybe some optional boundary checks as well. Depends on what values you feasibly expect as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you could try to use `strtotime` only if string is not 10-digit?

```
$str = '1356055871';
$timestamp = (preg_match('/\d{10}/',$str,$match))?(int)$str:strtotime($str);
echo $timestamp;
```

Regarding the question why you receive a value on first execution, and `false` in second one, this is because `1356532858` is interpreted as some valid date, although is not what you're expecting:

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime('1356532858'));
// outputs:   2858-08-27 13:56:53
```

`strtotime` can accept your timestamp, but should have a leading `@`:

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime('@1356532858'));
// outputs:   2012-12-26 15:40:58
```

Comment: a may have dates around Jan, 1970 so that's not an option

Comment: seems `Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC`is the threshold date (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a '@' in front of your timestamp.  This will instruct `strtotime` that this is a timestamp in Unix format:

```
var_dump(strtotime('@1356055871'));
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540894/why-does-a-unix-timestamp-need-to-be-prefixed-by-for-strtotime-to-understa)